# Basic configuration of SSH

Tags: ssh, permissions

For the most basic configuration of SSH I usually do these actions:

```
nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config && service ssh restart # Genral basic configuration like disabling all root logins;
nano ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && service ssh restart # Put your public keys inside;
chmod ~/.ssh 700
chmod ~/.ssh/authorized_keys 600
ssh USER@IP -vvv -L 22:localhost:22 # or USER@DOMAIN.TLD # Tunnel via SSH with verbose debugging
```

I was wondering if I should actually do `chmod ~/.ssh 700 -R` instead.

I asked about this in chat and terdon replied:

> I would expect chmod ~/.ssh 700 -R to break ssh since you just removed
>   read access from your config

Due to `700`, users in the same group as the owner and all other non-root users actually won't be able to read SSH data.

Is it problematic as long as the owner does have reading rights?

Comment: Why would you want the files to be executable? (and why do you restart the `ssh` service after changing `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`?)

Comment: You don't have to restart after editing `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, this file is read every time a connection (to this user) comes in. Not when the service is started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would expect chmod ~/.ssh 700 -R to break ssh since you just removed read access from your config

Uh, no?

```
-bash-4.2$ chmod -R 700 .ssh
-bash-4.2$ logout
...
% ssh somelinooxbox
...
-bash-4.2$ ls -l .ssh/authorized_keys
-rwx------ 1 jhqdoe xxxxxx 178 Aug 10  2018 .ssh/authorized_keys
-bash-4.2$
```

So that's not really a problem for this Centos7 test host for a non-`root` user (`root` is also fine with `chmod -R 700 ~/.ssh`).

A relevant question is "what user is the `sshd` process running as" which one might guess to either be `root`, or the user. `root` can typically read all files (with various exceptions for NFS or encrypted home dirs) and the user should have no problems reading a file marked as `rwx` to them. And we don't need to guess:

```
% ssh -o ControlMaster=no somelinooxbox
...
-bash-4.2$ sudo sysdig -p %user.uid fd.name = ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

And then elsewhere make a new connection; the `sysdig` shows the process that reads `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` as running as the user being connected to, who has sufficient permissions even after `chmod -R 700 ...` is run.

Granted, adding stray `+x` bits is at best needless and at worse might make something executable that really should not be, so see the other answer for the `X` trick, or otherwise ensure that directories get 0700 and files 0600.

(There can be complications from software such as selinux or apparmour, but that's merely an additional [can of bees](https://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2017/Jun/3) on top the usual permissions.)

Answer (score 2):

How about symbolic mode. Most modern `chmod`s, but not all can do this.

```
chmod -R go=,u=rwX ~/.ssh
```

This will give execute only to directories, remove permission to group and others, and give you full permissions.